# Detecting occluded face image

Tags: python, image-processing, occlusion

I have a face dataset, some of them contain partial occlusion, I want to discard the images with partial occlusion and keep only occlusion-free one. Partial occlusion may be sunglasses, hand, hair, etc. bellow is some examples.

[image] [image]

Can anyone please help me how can I detect occlusion in face images. Is there any algorithm or python library does this process. Any information will help me. Thanks

Comment: What kind of occlusion? Post some examples

Comment: @TA thank you for you reply. I edited the post.